# why cant find or load main class when extends TestCase class

Tags: java, junit

I encounter a interesting error by accident and I  need you help me figure it out.

as for the below code every thing is ok:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

then as for the follow code, something interesting come.

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class HelloWorld extends TestCase{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

when I run it, it says

> cant find or load main class.

I know when `jvm` load `HelloWorld class` it will load `TestCase class` first. So I make the below code segment.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException{
        Class.forName("junit.framework.TestCase");
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.TestCase

I dont know why? Maybe the `TestCase` class is not on my classpath ? But as for *the second code segment* I ensure `TestCase` is on my *classpath*.

---

So my question is:

1. Why can't I load `TestCase` class?
2. Why can't it find or load main class when extend `TestCase` class?

Note: I know the print *helloworld* function has nothing with `TestCase class` which used to *junit test* but I want to figure out the reason that bring this suprise.

Comment: You haven't shown us how you're running the code. It does indeed look like that junit isn't on the classpath... (As an aside, it would be a good idea to learn about using Markdown when formatting a question - and try to avoid using quoting and code for things like lists and notes.)

Comment: I run it in eclipse, and I will update my post.

Comment: So how have you ensure that JUnit is in your classpath in Eclipse? Have you tried running it from a command prompt with an explicit classpath?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet  thanks, it does the issue of classpath,  I use maven and the JUnit only play a role on test scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I dont know why? Maybe the TestCase class is not on my classpath ? But
>   as for the second code segment I ensure TestCase is on my classpath.

```
 Class.forName("junit.framework.TestCase");
```

returns the Class object associated with TestCase class. It doesn t set the classpath.

That's why you rise the exception :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   junit.framework.TestCase

You try to load a class which is not in the classpath.

To solve your problem with Eclipse, go in the properties windows of your project, then at the left, you have the Java Build Path option, go inside and look at the libraries tab. Here, you should add the JUnit library if you want JUnit  to be in the classpath.

Comment: "It has no relation with the classpath which is the path indicating the path of available classes and ressources during the java compilation or the running task." That's very misleading. `Class.forName` very much depends on the classpath. You seem to understand that for the rest of your answer, so it's unclear why you've said it has "no relation" with the classpath.

Comment: You are absolute right. Not taken the time to re read me. I modified it. Trying to make a full response in the train is probably not the best  idea :)  @Jon Skeet

Comment: That's definitely better :)

Comment: @GhostCat thank you :) I wish the same :) Not sure for a "care day" tomorrow. We will see :) See you :)